# Divergence of stress tensor in momentum transfer equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tensor-products, vector-analysis, tensors, differential-operators

Let suppose that we work in a 2D cartesian coordinates. what will be x and y components of
$\nabla.\left[-p I+\mu \left(\nabla \text{u}+(\nabla \text{u})^T\right)-\frac{2}{3} \mu (\nabla.\text{u})
 I \right]$

$p=p(x,y)$ is pressure, $\mu$ is viscosity and constant, $I$ is identity tensor and $\text{u}=u \hat i +v \hat j$ is velocity field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rule of thumb: the divergence of a matrix (a second order tensor) can be defined by the [trace of the gradient of a tensor field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_derivative_%28continuum_mechanics%29#Divergence_of_a_tensor_field).

For a $2\times 2$ matrix, the divergence is actually the divergence of each row:
$$
\nabla\cdot A = 
\begin{pmatrix}\nabla \cdot A_{1i}
\\
\nabla \cdot A_{2i} \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}\partial_{x} A_{11}+\partial_y A_{12}
\\
\partial_{x} A_{21} + \partial_y A_{22} \end{pmatrix}.
$$

- Pressure term $pI$:
  $$
  \nabla\cdot (pI) = \begin{pmatrix}\partial_{x} p
  \\
  \partial_{y} p\end{pmatrix} = \nabla p.
  $$
- The first term in the stress tensor is the first order strain tensor (by some factor of constants) $\nabla \mathbf{u}+(\nabla \mathbf{u})^T$: firstly when $\mathbf{u} = (u_1, u_2)
   = u_1 \mathbf{i} + u_2 \mathbf{j}$,
  $$
  \nabla \mathbf{u} = 
  \begin{pmatrix}\partial_{x} \mathbf{u}_1 & \partial_y\mathbf{u}_1
  \\
  \partial_{x} \mathbf{u}_2 & \partial_y\mathbf{u}_2 \end{pmatrix},
  $$
  and taking the divergence:
  $$
  \nabla\cdot\nabla \mathbf{u} = 
  \begin{pmatrix}\partial_{xx} \mathbf{u}_1 & \partial_{yy}\mathbf{u}_1
  \\
  \partial_{xx} \mathbf{u}_2 & \partial_{yy}\mathbf{u}_2 \end{pmatrix}.
  $$
  $\nabla \cdot (\nabla \mathbf{u})^T$ is left for you.
- For the second term in the stress tensor $(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}) I$:
  $$
  (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}) I = 
  \begin{pmatrix}\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} & 0
  \\
  0 & \nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}\end{pmatrix},
  $$
  and taking the divergence:
  $$
  \nabla\cdot \Big((\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}) I\Big) = 
  \begin{pmatrix} \partial_x (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} )
  \\
   \partial_y (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u})\end{pmatrix} = \nabla (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}).
  $$